# In Django Todo App how can each user have a distinct set of tasks?

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a todo app using Django. Currently, the problem I am facing is that no matter which user logs in, the same set of tasks appears, i.e. if a user adds some task for himself, they appear in every other user's todo list. **How can I modify my code so that each user can have a distinct set of tasks?**

Here's some of my code:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class To_DO_Fun(models.Model):
    Task_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    Task_Text = models.TextField(max_length=450, default='')
    Task_Done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Task_Name + '  --- is ---  ' + str(self.Task_Done)


class user_TODO(models.Model):
    User_Name = models.ForeignKey(To_DO_Fun , User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import To_DO_Fun, user_TODO #Class Name
from .forms import Form_todo, Form_Task #Form Name
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def HomeFun(request): #To view contents of the home page
    return render(request, "ToDo_Files/HomePage.html")


@login_required(login_url='Login-Page')
def Display_Page(request, User_Name_id):

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = Form_todo(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            all_items = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=User_Name_id)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ("Good Luck"))
            return render(request , 'ToDo_Files/Display_Page.html' , {'all_items': all_items} )

    else:
        form = Form_todo(request.POST or None)
        all_items = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=User_Name_id)
        return render(request,'ToDo_Files/Display_Page.html',{'all_items': all_items} )


@login_required(login_url='Login-Page')
def remove(request, To_DO_Fun_id):
    item = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=To_DO_Fun_id)
    item.delete()
    messages.success(request, ('Congratulations!!! You finished your task'))
    return redirect('Display-Page')


@login_required(login_url='Login-Page')
def data(request, To_DO_Fun_id):

        if request.method == "POST":
            item_all = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=To_DO_Fun_id)
            form = Form_Task(request.POST, instance= item_all)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                urlstr = 'ToDo_Files/details/'
                messages.success(request, ("Item Updated"))
                return redirect('Display-Page')

        else:
            item_all = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=To_DO_Fun_id)
            return render(request, 'ToDo_Files/details.html', {'item_all' : item_all})

        return redirect('Display-Page')


@login_required(login_url='Login-Page')
def Done_status(request, To_DO_Fun_id):
    item = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=To_DO_Fun_id)
    item.Task_Done = True
    item.save()
    return redirect('Display-Page')


@login_required
def Pen_status(request, To_DO_Fun_id):
    item = To_DO_Fun.objects.get(pk=To_DO_Fun_id)
    item.Task_Done = False
    item.save()
    return redirect('Display-Page')


def Reg_Fun(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        UserReg_Form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if UserReg_Form.is_valid():
            UserReg_Form.save()
            messages.success(request, ("Welcome"))
            return redirect('Login-Page')
    else:
        UserReg_Form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, "ToDo_Files/reg.html", {'UserReg_Form':UserReg_Form})

        return redirect('Login-Page')
```

Comment: What is your problem? It's hard to say what is your problem just inspecting the code.  Please edit your question and mention what you achieved and what you did not. BTW please have a look at PEP8, you are violating lots of naming conventions.

Comment: I designed a todo app. In it I was able to get the user to login and sign up and add, delete their tasks. But I want each user to see just his/her entered tasks, right now everyone is able to see the tasks list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a many-to-one-relationship from your tasks model to the `User` model.

in your `models.py`

```
class To_DO_Fun(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Task_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    Task_Text = models.TextField(max_length=450, default='')
    Task_Done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

then in your `views.py` you can retrieve all the tasks that belong to the user that is currently logged in using a filter.

```
tasks = To_DO_Fun.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
context = {'tasks': tasks}
return(request, "yourpage.html", context)
```

I suggest you take a look at [Django's coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) following the coding style will improve your code consistency and readability.

Comment: Can you guide me on the Many-to-one relation method.
Thanks

Comment: Your owner method works so far but I am not getting any data shown and when I add something I get an integrity error.

Comment: IntegrityError at /Display/
NOT NULL constraint failed: ToDo_Files_to_do_fun.owner_id

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Display/
Django Version: 1.11.20
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: ToDo_Files_to_do_fun.owner_id
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 328

Comment: I solved the error by using the direct db entry method in the view.
if request.method == "POST":
        print "request.POST",request.POST
        # form = Form_todo(request.POST or None)
        try:
            obj_todo = To_DO_Fun()
            obj_todo.Task_Name = request.POST.get('Task_Name')
            obj_todo.owner_id = request.POST.get('owner_id')
            obj_todo.save()

Comment: all_items = To_DO_Fun.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
            context = {'all_items': all_items}
            messages.success(request, ("Good Luck"))
        except Exception as ex:
            context['error_message'] = str(ex)
        return render(request , 'ToDo_Files/Display_Page.html', context)
    else:
        all_items = To_DO_Fun.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
        context = {'all_items': all_items}
        return render(request,'ToDo_Files/Display_Page.html',context )